# How to force xlwings to use COMRetryObjectWrapper instead of win32com api?

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I recently had to reformat my computer, and now whenever I try to call the Sheet.api property in xlwings, I get the following result:

```
>>> wb = xw.Book('<path-to-wb>')
>>> sht = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
>>> sht.api
    <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Worksheet instance at 0x1293314650312>
```

Previously, sht.api returned me a `<xlwings._xlwindows.COMRetryObjectWrapper at 0x1e816dda7c8>` object.

Is this some kind of windows configuration that I have to restore? Why is xlwings behaving differently all of a sudden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't all of a sudden but the effect of upgrading to a new version where the `RetryObjectWrapper` is printed with more meaningful information. It's still the same object though as you will see when you print its type:

```py
>>> type(sht.api)
<class 'xlwings._xlwindows.COMRetryObjectWrapper'>
```

Comment: So it's just a update to the __repr__ method of COMRetryObjectWrapper?